# Python string delete

Tags: python, string

I've got 2 problems:

1.I have a string and i want a function which  searches a$ for the first occurrence of b$ and returns the characters of a$ before the first occurrence of b$  like that :

> Input: MISSISSIPPI,P ==> OUTPUT==>MISSISSI

I made a program but removes only a string like that

```
word=input("Add word: ")
m=input("Add char:  ")
import re
removed=word.replace(m,"")
print(removed)
```

> Input:MISSISSIPPi ==> Output:MISSISSII

I want to delete also the last `"i"`

2.Another problem is also with a string , i want to split a given string (a$) into substrings each time the character b$ is found.

Comment: Is there supposed to be some significance to all of the $ characters you keep appending to the variable names in your description?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you import re? U can use it with **re.sub**:

```
import re

word=input("Add word: ")
m=input("Add char:  ")

result = re.sub('[{0}{1}]'.format(m.upper(), m.lower()), '', word)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basics; the rest you should be able to figure out yourself

1.

```
string = "MISSISSIPPI"
index = string.find(string, 'P')
result = string[:index]
```

2.

```
string = "MISSISSIPPI"
string.partition('P')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do these things with split, for example:

```
input = "MISSISSIPPI,P"

word, char = input.split(",")

substrings = word.split(char)

output = substrings[0]

print(output)

print(substrings)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text=input("Enter text:") #"Mississippi"
char=input("Enter character to remove:") #p
s=list()

for i in range(len(text)):

   if i!=(len(text)-1) and text[i]!=char: # when i=10 and text[i]="p"
      s+= text[i]



print("".join(s))
```